# Trouble Locating element on webpage

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans, selenium-webdriver

[HTML of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pWCW.jpg)

In selenium webdriver, I am trying to locate, then clear the textbox element in the given image with this code

```
driver.findElement(By.name("X")).clear();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=X][type=text]")).clear();
```

but neither of them work, giving the error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"X"}
```

and

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"input[name=X][type=text]"}
```

What am I doing incorrectly and how can fix it? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the page on which you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are some javascript shenanigans going on. Try waiting for the element to be located.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='X']")));
myDynamicElement.clear();
```

Comment: no, it returns this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='X']"}
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Answer (score 0):

For your second approach, can you please try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='X'][type='text']")).clear();
```

You missed out single quotes around `input` attributes' values.